# Does DashDB row organized tables support CLOBS?

Tags: blob, ibm-cloud, clob, dashdb

We are trying to store large CLOBS into a DashDB for analytics.  Yes, the table that has been created is row organized.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  KEY VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  MP3_FILE CLOB(250M) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(KEY)
) ORGANIZE BY ROW;
```

Even better would be if we can store BLOBS so we would not have to increase the file size by base64'ing.

However, even with CLOBS, we have the error:

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DASH107483.TEST, DRIVER=3.71.22

The code we are using is similar to:

```
PreparedStatement pre = connection.prepareStatement("insert into test (key,mp3_file) values (?,?)");
pre.setString(1, "test");
pre.setCharacterStream(2, new StringReader(encoded), encoded.length());
int count = pre.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();
logger.info("mergedMP3 file isUpdated: " + count);
pre.close();
connection.close();
```

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the issue is CLOB related. The error message is indicating that the table `DASH107483.TEST` wasn't found.

Any chance that table was created using lower case characters (e.g. the name was enclosed in double quotes in the DDL)?

`CREATE TABLE "test"(
  KEY VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  MP3_FILE CLOB(250M) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(KEY)
) ORGANIZE BY ROW;`

What's the output when you run

`SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA='DASH107483' ORDER BY TABNAME;`

Comment: After using an upper case name --> In the end, the setting of bytes rather than base64'ing was the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the use of bytes seems to work well.

```
PreparedStatement pre = connection.prepareStatement("insert into largespeechsynthesis(KEY,MP3_FILE) values (?,?)");
pre.setString(1, attachmentID.replace(".mp3", ""));
pre.setBytes(2, Files.readAllBytes(mergedFile.toPath()));
int count = pre.executeUpdate();
logger.info("mergedMP3 file isUpdated: " + count);
connection.commit();
pre.close();
connection.close();
```